# subsetting in a specific sequence of time points in R, can I use seq?

Tags: r, subset, data-management

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
structure(list(A = c(70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70), T = c(0.1, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6), X = c(434.01, 434.01, 434.75, 434.75, 434.75, 
434.01), Y = c(454.92, 454.92, 454.92, 454.92, 454.18, 454.92
), V = c(0, 0, 21.128, 0, 14.94, 14.94), thetarad = c(0.151841552716899, 
0.151841552716899, 0.150990672182432, 0.150990672182432, 0.150177486839524, 
0.151841552716899), thetadeg = c(8.69988012340509, 8.69988012340509, 
8.6511282599214, 8.6511282599214, 8.6045361718215, 8.69988012340509
)), .Names = c("A", "T", "X", "Y", "V", "thetarad", "thetadeg"
), row.names = 1423:1428, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to subset specific time points in R with intervals of 30 sec. I can do this by manually subsetting each time point that I want:

```
a1=subset(binA, T==0.1)
a2=subset(binA, T==30)
a3=subset(binA, T==60)
a4=subset(binA, T==90)
a5=subset(binA, T==120)
a6=subset(binA, T==150)
a7=subset(binA, T==180)
a8=subset(binA, T==210)
a9=subset(binA, T==240)
a10=subset(binA, T==270)
a11=subset(binA, T==300)
a12=subset(binA, T==330)
a13=subset(binA, T==360)
a14=subset(binA, T==390)
a15=subset(binA, T==420)
a16=subset(binA, T==450)
a17=subset(binA, T==480)
a18=subset(binA, T==510)
a19=subset(binA, T==540)
a20=subset(binA, T==570)
a21=subset(binA, T==599.5)
```

I tried subsetting using `sapply`and the `seq` function but got confusing results. I also want to count the unique A in each subset of data. I also know I can do this using the `count` function in `plyr`package.

```
a1=count(unique(subset(binA, T==0.1)))
```

but count will work with one data frame and not multiple ones (correct me if I am wrong). I also want to take the means of thetadeg for each subset (this should be easy for sapply in one data frame only). So I need help on how to write a function with specific seq points.

I know this problem is trivial but help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `cut` or `findInterval` would be of use here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming data is in `df` data frame then, try this:

```
sapply(c(0.1,seq(30,599,30),599.5),
       function(x)
         length(unique(df[ df$T==x, "A"])))
```

Comment: Yes! I just did not know how to input the `seq`. Now I can also get the mean by changing the last part to `mean(unique(binA[ binA$T==x, "thetadeg"])))`THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following code to get what you want. This doesn't look for 0.1 and 599.5 but that should be easy to manipulate.

```
timeintervals <- seq(0,600, 30)
for(i in 1:length(timeintervals)
{
  # create the subsets for each time interval
  assign(
    paste0("a",i),
    df[df$T == timeintervals[i],]
    )

  # get all unique As
  assign(
    paste0("b",i),
    unique(df[df$T == timeintervals[i],"A"])
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function I think you want is `split`:

```
 subsetted.by.T <- split(dfrm, dfrm$T)
lapply(subsetted.by.T, nrow)

$`0.1`
[1] 1

$`0.2`
[1] 1

$`0.3`
[1] 1

$`0.4`
[1] 1

$`0.5`
[1] 1

$`0.6`
[1] 1

> subsetted.by.T[[1]]
      A   T      X      Y V  thetarad thetadeg
1423 70 0.1 434.01 454.92 0 0.1518416  8.69988
```

If you want to name these individual items, then the `names<-` function would be appropriate:

```
names(subsetted.by.T) <- paste0("a", seq(length(subsetted.by.T) ) )
```

If the "T" column were somewhat irregular in its values, then perhaps using `cut` to create categories at regular breaks would be useful for the purpose of splitting. The question might be clarified if "T" were actually a time value. At the moment it's a "numeric" value, but there are cut methods for datetime classes.

Comment: I know split and I thought of using it but I need my data to be on intervals not on all time points. Thanks!

Comment: That means you should use 'cut'.

Answer (score 0):

If purpose is just to get average, unique count etc, you don't need to subset.and one more thing, id T factor is is continuous and you need to make the bins? here I am assuming factor

here is one approach with `plyr`

```
ddply(df,~T,summarise,l=length(unique((A))))
ddply(df,~T,summarise,m=mean(thetadeg))
```

Comment: I need my data to be on intervals not on all time points. Thanks!